# oci: set sqlnet.expire_time without sqlnet.ora file

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

I can set in sqlnet.ora the parameter SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF209

I need this as a keepalive for a connection through a firewall.
How can I set directly this Parameter in OCI (oracle call interface - the C API) without sqlnet.ora?

Greetings and thanks
Urs

Comment: Any luck with this? (I have a similar problem: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93394/is-it-possible-to-configure-sqlnet-tns-admin-options-without-sqlnet-ora-file)

Answer (score 0):

No, because it is a server-side only parameter, for the listener. You cannot set it with OCI.